# Create a mapping that works whilst searching

Tags: key-bindings, map-operator

I have `jk` remapped to `<Esc>` in insert mode and for some reason my brain always want's to exit a search by typing `jk`. I would like to remap `jk` to `<CR>` when performing a search. I.e typing `/searchjk` will put me in normal mode with the cursor over the next occurrence of 'search'. Is there a special mapping mode for search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `:cnoremap`, which works for search `/` but also for Ex commands, that you enter with `:`. See [`:help :map-modes`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-modes) for more information on the map modes available.

(To be exact, there are a few more cases where the command-line mappings apply, such as the `input()` function, or entering an expression for the expression register with `<C-R>=` from Insert mode, etc.)

If using this mapping for both modes is acceptable to you, then the following should work:

```
cnoremap jk <CR>
```

If you want to cover *only* search mode, then you can use the [`getcmdtype()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#getcmdtype%28%29) function to only expand the mapping in that case. Use an [`<expr>`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Amap-expression) mapping to evaluate the function.

```
cnoremap <expr> jk getcmdtype() =~ '^[/?]$' ? '<CR>' : 'jk'
```

We're using a [`=~`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#expr-%3D%7E) regular expression match to cover both `/` for a forward search and a `?` for a backward search.

Note that the mapping acts on all the command-line modes (including an Ex command, `input()` box, expression register), just it expands back to `jk` in the cases where it's not in a search context. In particular, this will make the `j` delay when typing it in a command (Vim will wait for the next character to see whether to trigger the mapping or not.) You can possibly improve on this by adding an `<expr>` mapping for `k` alone, then checking whether it's preceded by a `j` (use `getcmdline()` and `getcmdpos()`) and in that case producing a sequence that will erase the `j` (with a backspace) and produce the `<CR>` that will execute the search. It's doable, but quite some work...

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted :) Having the mapping for `k` is a really neat idea. Maybe I'll try something similar for insert mode next time I'm in the mood for some tinkering.